# Why are p-trap j-bends reversed depending on application?

Tags: plumbing, drain, drain-waste-vent, p-trap

Whenever I install P-traps under sinks (eg, usually inside a cabinet or the like, but outside of a wall, using threaded fittings), the asymmetrical J-bend has the straight side towards the drain and swooping side towards the sewer.

Whenever I install P-traps in a hidden way (eg, in a wall or under the floor, usually cementing them), the asymmetrical J-bend has the straight side towards the sewer and the swooping side towards the drain.

Why is this?

My own expectation would be that all P-traps should be installed like under a sink, with the swooping side towards the sewer, so there's less resistance to push things through the swoop towards the sewer. But that's just my random opinion.

Under sink:

[image: under sink]

In wall:

[image: in wall]

Answer (score 0):

The asymmetry must be a quirk of the manufacturing process. From ASTM D3311:

> 3.3 The exact outside shape of a ﬁtting is not determined by the outline drawings shown in this specification but rather by the socket dimensions, wall thickness requirements, waterway, laying lengths, and any other critical dimensions that may be specified.

They don't like pictures on Stack Exchange without a link, so looking at the image of the p-trap from D3311, it shows a nice clean radius without the asymmetry that you've noticed. They specify "union seal" and "solvent weld joint" alternatives with the same symmetrical geometry. They specify a bunch of minimum dimensions like vertical hub center to vertical hub center. There's no bounds fixed for the fitting's bend radius, however, where I believe that this rationalizes why quality control accepts the manufacturing quirk that you've noticed.

Comment: that the are all made like this today points to some reason, not a quirk of manufacturing.

Comment: @TigerGuy, they're not all made like this. Hub upstream and spigot or threads on the downstream side, they tend to be symmetrical.

Answer (score 0):

Anecdotally (meaning according to randos on the internet), this design is based on the [Brachistochrone Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachistochrone_curve), which makes the flow faster and therefore self-scouring.  This would be the more vertical section as the inlet and the less vertical side towards the discharge.  Whether the engineering is valid or not, who can say?  But it is clearly a design decision made by someone somewhere once upon a time.

Plumbers sometimes say it doesn't matter, sometimes use the phrase "hard in, easy out."  I doubt you would ever notice the difference if it were installed reversed.

Comment: I don't think the brachistochrone curve is relevant here - that curve minimizes the transit time, it doesn't maximize speed. In the ideal case, the speed through the pipe is determined only by the vertical drop, the shape of the pipe is irrelevant - ideally, water will go through *any trap of this depth* at the same speed. This design helps the water avoid making a sharp turn as it accelerates downward, but the brachistochrone curve assumes lossless cornering anyway.

Comment: A cycloid is symmetrical. A fitting shape based on that would be more boxy than a circle, but symmetrical.